# How to handle empty (none) tuple returned from python function

Tags: python

I have a function that either returns a tuple or None. How is the Caller supposed to handle that condition?

```
def nontest():
  return None

x,y = nontest()

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: The best option, if possible, is to change the called function so it will always return a tuple, possibly `(None, None)`

Comment: What do you want to do if the function returns `None`? What should `x` be in that case? What should `y` be in that case? Do you even really want to continue with the current calculation that uses `x` and `y`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
x,y = nontest() or (None,None)
```

If nontest returns a two-item tuple like it should, then x and y are assigned to the items in the tuple.  Otherwise, x and y are each assigned to none.  Downside to this is that you can't run special code if nontest comes back empty (the above answers can help you if that is your goal).  Upside is that it is clean and easy to read/maintain.

Answer (score 11):

[EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp):

```
try:
    x,y = nontest()
except TypeError:
    # do the None-thing here or pass
```

or without try-except:

```
res = nontest()

if res is None:
    ....
else:
    x, y = res
```

Comment: what about [PEP 3132](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)? is it relevant somehow?

Comment: I am not sure if you can assume (yet) that the OP means Python3.x if tagged Python.

Comment: Even for 3.x, I don't think it's relevant here. First, you'd have to write `x, *y = nontest()`, then if `y` is empty do the `None`-thing, otherwise do `y = y[0]`, which I think isn't as clean as either of the two options. But, more importantly, `x, *y = nontest()` will still fail on `None`; you'd have to change `nontest` to `return `None,)` instead. At which point you might as well just `return None, None` and then you don't need extended unpacking.

Answer (score 5):

If you can change the function itself, it's probably a better idea to make it raise a relevant exception instead of returning `None` to signal an error condition. The caller should then just `try`/`except` that.

If the `None` *isn't* signalling an error condition, you'll want to rethink your semantics altogether.

Comment: Or, if it's perfectly appropriate to return nothing, you should probably be returning `(None, None)` or some other value that _is_ a 2-tuple, instead of `None`.

Comment: Also, it's `try`/`except`, not `try`/`catch`.

Comment: @abarnert: you're right, of course. I haven't even touched Java in half a decade, but it still haunts me.

Comment: For me, it's C++, not Java… I think part of the problem is that there's no good verb for `except`. So where a Java/C++ user would say "try it, and catch the error", a Python user has to say "try it, and handle the error with an except". Since that's clumsy, we keep using "catch" as a verb, which means in non-code contexts it's easy to accidentally write `try`/`catch`.